# Looking to call a SSRS report with a parameter from VB.Net code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing

I have a SSRS report that contains a parameter called @playerID

Can you show me what coding I need to add so the report can be run using the parameter?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim reportParameters() As Int16 = {10}

    Me.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)
End Sub
```

When I run the report, no data is shown unless I comment out the 2nd line of code and use RefreshReport which in that case it will prompt me to input the parameter with a 10 and that works.

Answer (score 1):

This code will loop through an array of parameters and add them to a reportviewer. You should make a `getParameterName(int)` method to get the names for the rv.

```
int[] parameters = new int[1];
parameters[0] = 10;

//Create Parameter Collection Array
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new       Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[parameters.Length];
//Loop through each parameter and load the name and value into the parameter collection
int i = 0;
foreach (int parameter in parameters)
{
   reportParameterCollection[i] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter();
   reportParameterCollection[i].Name = getParameterName(i);
   reportParameterCollection[i].Values.Add((parameters[i]);
   i++;
}

//Load Parameters into the ReportViewer
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

**More of a C# guy myself, but here's my hand at vb.net in 5 seconds:**

```
Dim paramList As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)

paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("Report_Parameter1","")

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList)
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a VB.Net version of this code? I'm also calling the report from a WinForm with the report viewer control.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with   
     paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("PlayerID", 10))

        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList)
        ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() 
but it stills shows up as a blank report. Is there a setting in the report I also have to change?